# ATMEGA128 AVR MEMORY ERRORS

Tags: c, memory, avr, atmega

I have code for ATMEGA128. It should be a counter program from 0 to 9.

```
#include "iom128v.h"
#include "macros.h"

void delay(int ms)
{
 int c1, c2;
 for(c1=0;c1<ms;c1++)
  for(c2=0;c2<970;c2++) NOP();
}

void main()
{
 char seg[10]={0b01110111, 0b01100000, 0b00111110, 0b01111010, 0b01101001,
  0b01011011, 0b01011111, 0b01110000,0b01111111, 0b01111011};
 char i;
 DDRC=0b10000111;
 DDRA=0xFF; 
 DDRG=0x01; 
 PORTG=0;   
 PORTA=0;   
 PORTC=0;   
 PORTC=5;   
 PORTC=7;   
 PORTA=0xFF; 
 PORTC=1;        
 PORTC=2;        
 PORTC=6;        
 while(1)
 {
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
   PORTA=~seg[i];  
   delay(300);  
  }
 }
}
```

I run this code in proteus and get the following errors cycled

PC=0x00FC. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21E1]=AA. [U1]

PC=0x0132. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21FF]=99. [U1]

PC=0x0132. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21FE]=00. [U1]

PC=0x0168. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D6]=21. [U1]

PC=0x016A. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D5]=D7. [U1]

PC=0x016C. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D4]=02. [U1]

PC=0x016E. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D3]=00. [U1]

PC=0x0174. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21FD]=BA. [U1]

PC=0x0174. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21FC]=00. [U1]

PC=0x01E0. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D2]=0A. [U1]

PC=0x01E2. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D1]=02. [U1]

PC=0x01E4. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D0]=D7. [U1]

PC=0x01E6. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21CF]=21. [U1]

PC=0x01E8. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Write while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21CE]=7B. [U1]

PC=0x01EA. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D5]. [U1]

PC=0x01EC. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D6]. [U1]

PC=0x01EE. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D3]. [U1]

PC=0x01F0. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D4]. [U1]

PC=0x0202. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21CE]. [U1]

PC=0x0204. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21CF]. [U1]

PC=0x0206. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D0]. [U1]

PC=0x0208. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D1]. [U1]

PC=0x020A. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21D2]. [U1]

PC=0x000E. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21FC]. [U1]

PC=0x0174. [AVR MEMORY] External Memory Read while interface is not enabled (SRE=0): [0x21FD]. [U1]

PC=0x0000. [AVR CPU] RET address = 0x0000 [U1]

Comment: Looks like you're having trouble reading and writing external memory while the interface is not enabled.

Comment: Did this help at all https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62089/error-in-proteus-simulation-using-atmega16-with-arduino-ide looks like you could be selecting the wrong device type in proteus simulation?

Comment: How can i fix this? I don't know what interface is not enabled.

Comment: Make sure the device you included in proteus (it's a schematic layout program, correct?) matches the device you compiled the code for. I don't have experience with either of these so I'm kind of stabbing in the dark unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not having wrong device for sure, i have schematic from my teacher.

Comment: Your teacher can be wrong.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sk5bq8 here

Comment: Are you sure it should be #include "iom128v.h" instead of #include "iom128.h"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to use external memory. This access must stack access. Check for stack address.
Of course, Proteus has a lot of weird behaviors in simulation.

In case of eXternal MEMmory access:
You must set SRE bit on MCUCR register to enable External Memory Interface. Also check configuration for MCUCR.SRW10, XMCRA and XMCRB. XMCRA and XMCRB are not accessible on ATmega103 compatibility mode (M103C fuse programmed).
When SRE bit is set, the A, C and G[2:0] will be dedicated to XMEM interface (instead of normal GPIO port).
(Also see  for better busy-wait delay automated base on F_CPU macro.)

Answer (score 0):

There is limitation of simulation of external memory in proteus, so avoid using external memory.
I have done many programs but avoided external memory, kindly check proteus website.